# Calling an overriden function in java

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding, parent-child, subclass

I'm writing a piece of code in which I need to call an overridden method of a parent class. This is easy to do in C++:

```
class A{
  public:
    void doPrint() {
        print();
    }
    
    void print(){
      cout << "This is A" << endl;
    }
};

class B: public A{
  public:
    void doPrint() {
        print();
    }
    
    void print(){
      A::doPrint();
    }
};

int main() {
  B b;
  b.doPrint();

  return 0;
}
```

However, I need to do this in java. My current java implementation trying to emulate this behavior from C++ is:

```
class A {
    public void doPrint() {
        this.print();
    }
    
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("This is A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void doPrint() {
        this.print();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void print() {
        super.doPrint(); 
    }
    
}

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.doPrint();
    }
}
```

However, when I do this I get a stackoverflow error caused by an infinite loop of doPrint and print:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at A.doPrint(A.java:4)
    at B.print(B.java:12)
    at A.doPrint(A.java:4)
    at B.print(B.java:12)
    at A.doPrint(A.java:4)
    at B.print(B.java:12)
    at A.doPrint(A.java:4)
    at B.print(B.java:12)
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do in Java? I'm having trouble seeing where my logic is going wrong.

Comment: seeing as you don't want to call the overridden methods, don't override them. also, try by just: super.print() instead of super.doPrint()

Comment: Did you try debugging to see the flow it takes?

Comment: I suppose you'll get the same behaviour in C++ if you declare your C++ methods as `virtual`

Answer (score 0):

For instances of B, A's `doPrint()` which calls `this.print()` invokes the *instance's* implementation of `print()`, ie B's `print()`.

`this.print()` does *not* mean "the implementation of `print()` declared in this class".

`this.print()` is the same as just `print()` - qualifying it with `this.` is both implied and redundant.